# How do I remove new lines before and after formatting tags, while also ignoring user comments?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find a way to delete excess new lines between opening and closing formatting tags and a user's comment. An example of this might be:

```
[b]


this is a long comment




[/b]
```

I want the output to look like: `[b]this is a long comment[/b]`.

I wrote this regex to target all new lines between these tags, but to ignore the content of a user's comment:

`#(?<=\[b\])(\R+?)(?=.*?(\R+?)(?=\[\/b\]))#i`.

I thought this would work, as my example on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CPNu4y/10) shows capturing of the correct new lines, but it doesn't actually do anything when I use it like this:

```
$regex = "#(?<=\[b\])(\R+?)(?=.*?(\R+?)(?=\[\/b\]))#i";
$content = preg_replace($regex, "", $content);
```

I'm very new to regex, so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: [The answer is painfully simple](https://regex101.com/r/YyJr32/2)

Comment: Ha, if this works it will be quite embarrassing. Let me try it.

Comment: If that string is inside a larger string, and the content itself can contain line breaks, you may use [`preg_replace("#(\[b])\s*(.*?)\s*(\[/b])#is", '$1$2$3', $content);`](https://ideone.com/3CyDsP). To only remove linebreaks, use [`"#(\[b])\R*(.*?)\R*(\[/b])#is"`](https://ideone.com/sDKMkr) regex.

Comment: @emsimpson92 Note that that will replace every newline

Comment: Well it does work. I told you I was new :)

Since I'm here, what would I do if I only wanted to target new lines that come after and before the formatting tags only? So, for example: `[b]\n\n\n\here's a comment \n here's another comment \n\n\n[/b]` I don't want to remove the new lines between the comments, just before [/b] and after [b].

Comment: @Thefourthbird good catch. For some reason I missed the "between the tags" specification. Whoops.

Comment: I just saw Wiktor's answer, which works exactly as I hoped. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all line breaks after `[b]` and before `[/b]` you may use

```
preg_replace("#(\[b])\R*(.*?)\R*(\[/b])#is", '$1$2$3', $content);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/sDKMkr) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fi3Yx8/1).

In case you want to also remove *blank* lines and leading/trailing whitespace, you may use

```
preg_replace("#(\[b])\s*(.*?)\s*(\[/b])#is", '$1$2$3', $content);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/3CyDsP) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fi3Yx8/2).

**Details**

- `(\[b])` - Group 1 (later referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): a `[b]` substring
- `\R*` - 0+ line breaks (or if `\s*` is used, 0+ whitespaces)
- `(.*?)` - Group 2 (later referred to with `$2` from the replacement pattern): any 0+ chars, as few as possible (it matches line breaks, too, due to the `s` modifier)
- `\R*` - 0+ line breaks (or if `\s*` is used, 0+ whitespaces)
- `(\[/b])` - Group 3 (later referred to with `$3` from the replacement pattern): a `[/b]` substring.